# Bootstrap - Align A tag and H2 in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a h2-Heading and a href-style-button vertically aligned using Bootstrap 3 - I have been experimenting with that for an hour now. How do I do it correctly? this shall keep responsiveness ...

heading has to be aligned on the left, href aligned to the right (that's why I used pull-right class), but the text of both shall be on the same thought horizontal line.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h2><b>Clubnews</b></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right" href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> neuer Beitrag
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want we help you faster, please provide us a jsFiddle link with your code inside.

Comment: use `class="pull-left"` to `h2`.

Comment: With a little help from CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/Lq6u5401/

Comment: @juno_okyo, this is not a good practice when you are with a css framework like Bootstrap.

Comment: @FrayneKonok I know it'll override the default CSS (of Bootstrap), so we can create a new class name or using the style attribute like your answer xD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Complete solution:**

By default H2 has some padding, so to match equal i have added a style into the second `div`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h2 class="pull-left"><b>Clubnews</b></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6"  style="padding: 15px">
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right" href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> neuer Beitrag
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the padding was the important thing I missed, thanks!